# In VBA how do create nested if statements for Select Case Target.Value?

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, rows

I have this VBA code for Excel. The entire goal is to hide and unhide rows depending on some input values located in cells M7, H11, K11, and O11. The latter is reflected in the code below. The issue I have is that the rows that are being hidden in the first case target, are also located in the next three case targets. For example if I hide rows 20:23 when H11 is "yes", then I choose "2" in  M7, those rows become unhidden (which makes sense given the range 10:57 of the case), and I want the results caused by H11 = "yes" to be "remembered", for a lack of a better word. I am not sure how to tackle this, and am not sure if its some "nested if" problem. Any help or redirection would be appreciated. See: [Workbook Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/chhkS.png)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
ActiveSheet.Activate
If Not Application.Intersect(Range("M7"), Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
        Select Case Target.Value
        Case Is = "1":  Rows("10:33").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                        Rows("34:178").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Case Is = "2":  Rows("10:57").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                        Rows("58:178").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Case Is = "3":  Rows("10:81").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                        Rows("82:178").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Case Is = "4":  Rows("10:105").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                        Rows("106:178").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Case Is = "5":  Rows("10:129").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                        Rows("130:178").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Case Is = "6":  Rows("10:153").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                        Rows("154:178").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Case Is = "7":  Rows("10:177").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                        Rows("178:179").EntireRow.Hidden = True
      Case Else
    End Select
  End If

If Not Application.Intersect(Range("H11"), Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
        Select Case Target.Value
        Case Is = "Yes":  Rows("20:23").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                        Rows("24:24").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Case Is = "No":  Rows("20:23").EntireRow.Hidden = True
                        Rows("24:24").EntireRow.Hidden = False
      Case Else
    End Select
  End If

If Not Application.Intersect(Range("K11"), Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
        Select Case Target.Value
        Case Is = "Yes":  Rows("24:27").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                        Rows("28:28").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Case Is = "No":  Rows("24:27").EntireRow.Hidden = True
                        Rows("28:28").EntireRow.Hidden = False     
      Case Else
    End Select
  End If

If Not Application.Intersect(Range("O11"), Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
        Select Case Target.Value
        Case Is = "Yes":  Rows("28:31").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                        Rows("32:32").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Case Is = "No":  Rows("28:31").EntireRow.Hidden = True
                        Rows("32:32").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End Select
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: It surely can be handled. Why don't you have a think and then accurately describe what should happen in which case? Let's say you have decided that the case `H11` has precedence. What about the cases `K11` and `O11`? How should they behave considering that they also hide/unhide rows from the first two cases?

Comment: Start by exiting the event handler if there's no intersect between `Target` and `Range("M7,H11,K11,O11")`: after that just run all the checks in reverse order of importance (i.e. if you check A to override check B then put check A *after* check B)

Comment: @VBasic2008, and Tim Williams, for some odd reason I never thought about priority/hierarchy, let me take that into account and refactor. Thanks for the advice!